# What is the correct way to wire a utility light with an outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I had a light fixture in a utility closet go out. The replacement fixture has an outlet but my original light did not have an outlet This complicates things for someone like myself.

And I wish I had taken a picture of the wiring before I messed with it, but I didn't.

Below is a picture of how I currently have it, and I need to know what I should do next.

The previous light had 2 white wires coming into Terminal A, and 2 black wires coming into Terminal C.  But in the new light, I could not get 2 wires to fit.  What did this accomplish?  Is the way I have the wiring of the neutral and hot wires OK?  The light turns on, but is it safe.

As for the bare ground wires (labeled D).  I assume that goes to Terminal C.  But do both of the bare wires go to the terminal? Or just one of them? How exactly should this be wired?

*Also, I have this circuit switched off while working.  Just flipped it on to see that it worked and snap the photos.*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would connect the safety ground wires that are currently twisted to a third bar wire pigtail which would then connect to the terminal that you have labeled B. (This would match much the same as you have shown the black and white wire sets to be pig tailed).

Be aware that the outlet of this new fixture will be a switched outlet if this light is turned on and off by the separate remote switch that you described in another question. Normally this type of light fixture would be used when connected to a non-switched circuit so the outlet is live all the time and then the light itself turned on and off via the pull chain.

If you have concerns regarding the safety of an outlet like this you may consider getting a ceramic base light socket that does not have the socket. They are readily available and not very expensive.

Comment: If it's switched from a real light switch, then swap that fixture for one without the pull cord. Otherwise you'll have a troubleshooting issue everytime you turn the installed light switch on, and the light doesn't come on.  One without receptacle or pull cord is about $1.

Comment: @Harper. Good point, I took back the outlet one and swapped it out for what was there before.   Although, after your other answer..https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/140669/1296 I may have to change it again!